# Derivative of an Expectation over an Indicator function

Tags: expectation

I have a small question on how to compute the derivative of an expectation when an indicator function gets in the way. Let $x$ be a random variable. We are interested in computing the derivative wrt A of

$E_x [(A-x)1_{(x \leq A)}]$

where $1_n$ is the indicator function 1 when $n$ is true. A paper I am reading mentions that this is simply

$F(A)$

but I am unsure how to get that result. Your intuitive explanations are most appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty clear that $E[1_{(x\leq A)}]$ is $F(A)$, so I don't think it's also true for $E[(A-x)1_{(x\leq A)}]$.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: I see that.  Yes that makes a big difference.

Comment: I posted an answer below, let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E_x [(A-x)1_{(x \leq A)}]$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(A-x)1_{(x\leq A)}p_x(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^A(A-x)p_x(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^AAp_x(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^Axp_x(x)dx$$
$$=A\int_{-\infty}^Ap_x(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^Axp_x(x)dx$$
$$=AF(A)-\int_{-\infty}^Axp_x(x)dx$$

So taking the derivative with respect to $A$ we get
$$F(A) + AF'(A)-\frac{d}{dA}\int_{-\infty}^Axp_x(x)dx$$
$$=F(A)+Ap_x(A)-Ap_x(A)$$
$$=F(A)$$

Comment: You're welcome glad to help